# Accessing multiple controllers per page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've started moving my angularJS controllers into separate files for the sake of readability, however I found this causes the controller defined in a separate file to not run at all. However, I'm wondering if this has to do with my MakeGray.html being in a separate folder from MakeGray.js?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0aSl.jpg

When the drop down menu item selected is MakeGray it will inject the following html

```
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/opencv_css.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MakeGray">    

    <div class="row">
      <div class ="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5">
    <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model-->
    <button ng-click="MakeGray_Button()">Make Gray</button>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="../../js/jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="../../js/MakeGray.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

js app

```
var app = angular.module("app", [
    "MakeGray",
    "ui.bootstrap"
]);
```

js MakeGray

```
    var MakeGray = angular.module("MakeGray", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

MakeGray.controller("MakeGray",["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
      alert("HELLO"); // Doesn't even get to hello when I click on the MakeGray button
}]);
```

My firebug outputs no errors

Comment: Hi, your code runs fine. I'd check if all your JS files referenced correctly.

Comment: There are no warnings and no errors that suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by the title, you're only trying to access one controller on this page. Anyway the functionality you're trying to get works.. heres a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgXRjb3bLd2RIfv3hQBP). I will note that you have to wrap the alert in a $scope function to make it fire with the button.

```
var MakeGray = angular.module("MakeGray", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

MakeGray.controller("MakeGray",["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){
  $scope.MakeGray_Button = function(){
    alert("HELLO"); // Does get to hello when I click on the MakeGray button
  }
}]);
```

Comment: I should also mention that the MakeGray.html is called from an ng-include template.url within my MainController within index.html

http://pastebin.com/hTdfwd2t

Sorry I should've mentioned this before...

Comment: When I do an alert("HELLO") outside of the MakeGray.controller I notice that it does go off.

Comment: I just changed the plnkr to reflect the ng-include

Comment: what... "'MakeGray'" what on earth is this syntax? O.o web dev is very confusing, I will try this right now

Comment: grrr.. not working it is saying 404 template.url not found

Comment: You must be referencing the files wrong. Can you just try to put them all in the same file so you can eliminate that as an issue?

Comment: When I hardcode the MakeGray.html as ../opencv/MakeGray/MakeGray.html the error goes away, but when I click the button nothing pops up either. I will try putting them all in one file though.

Comment: I put them in the same folder and the alert("Hello") still doesn't fire.